# Retrival time of orient DB while finding paths between 2 vertex

Tags: graph, gremlin, orientdb

We have  a use case where we need to to use graph db.There are around

10000 nodes and  1000000 edges (approx).

Now i need to query like this. For any 2 vertex find all possible paths between them.

How much time origntDb will take for it?I want retrival time to be very minimal.Is this supported by orientDB?

The distance of two vertex will be around 20.But each vertex may have around 10 outgoing edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all paths between vertex 1 and 2 in Gremlin, do:

```
g.v(1).out.loop(1){true}{it.object.id==2}.path
```

Of course, all possible paths are infinite if you have cycles, so you will probably want to do this:

```
g.v(1).out.loop(1){true}{it.object.id==2}.path[0..100]
```

...to get at most 100 paths. You can also do this to remove cyclic paths:

```
g.v(1).out.simplePath.loop(2){true}{it.object.id==2}.path[0..100]
```

Marko.

Comment: @Marko, couldn't the second example get stuck in an infinite loop since Gremlin does depth-first search?

Comment: As of today, I don't think any of these examples for dealing with cycles work.

Answer (score 1):

use the shortestPath() function bundled with OrientDB:

```
select shortestPath(#8:32, #8:10)
```

Where the 2 RIDs are the record ids of the 2 nodes.

Comment: Thanks for replying.But my question was about retrival time and performance .How much time will it take for this kind of retrival of all paths(not only shortest)?I have mentioned it in detail in my original post.Can you comment on it?

Comment: With a hot cache this could takes less than 10ms, but depends by your hw/sw configuration and how vertices are connected.